# SMS Verification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms

I am working on creating SMS verification for an app, and have found the tutorial on RubySource here: http://rubysource.com/adding-sms-capabilities-to-your-rails-app/.

I am pretty new to Rails and cannot seem to figure out how to create the view file for *Users#new* that it says I need to make in *app/views/users*.

Would love some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view file is nothing special, it is just a regular text file, with a contrived extension. In this case, your filename should be `new.html.erb`, in the referenced location. You can just make it an empty text file, and put their code in it.

The filename is derived by convention - the first part (new) is the action, the second part is the type that will be rendering (html), and the 3rd part is the rendering engine that is used (erb).